# router.navigate changes url but the view won't change

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, routes

i am having trouble when using router.navigate on a click listener for a marker in googlemaps. The page url changes to the desired path but the outlet wont change the view.

```js
loadEquipos(locacion:  Locacion) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.equipos.length; i++) {
      if(this.equipos[i].idLocacion === locacion.id) {
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.equipos[i].mapData.center.lat, this.equipos[i].mapData.center.lng),
          map: map,
          label: {
            color: 'black',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            text: this.equipos[i].nombre,
          },
          idEquipo: this.equipos[i].id
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/tanque', marker.idEquipo]);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Thats the method in witch the event listener is added.

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'admLocaciones',
        component: AdmLocacionesComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/inicio',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'inicio',
        component: InicioComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'buscarLocacion/:id',
        component: BuscarLocacionComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'editarLocacion/:id',
        component: EditarLocacionComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'nuevaLocacion',
        component: NuevaLocacionComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'admRegiones',
        component: AdmRegionesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'locacion/:id',
        component: LocacionComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tableroTanque',
        component: TableroTanqueComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'tanque/:id',
        component: TanqueComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
```

and those are my paths, any other navigation works perfectly fine inside the app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those paths work if you type them into the browser address bar?

Comment: yes, if i reload the page after the path changed with the navigate function it loads the view that's supposed to.

Comment: Is there anything displayed in the console? Is this ` marker.idEquipo` definitely set to a value? Try turning on event tracing and see if that tells you anything. (The syntax of your navigate call looks correct.)

Comment: No, theres nothing in the console, and the value for idEquipo is set correctly since on the url change it displays /tanque/2 for example(being 2 the value i want to navigate to).

Comment: Does event tracing provide any insight?

Comment: i have no idea what event tracing is.. gonna read up on that and see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. As it turns out, if the params don't change in the path, then the component won't be reinitialized. Since your path is 'tanque/:id' you need to use Observables to detect when the param has changed and trigger an update.

The Angular Router tutorial has a great example of using routes with params and how to incorporate Observables: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 2):

Somehow adding de listener inside a Google.Maps.Listener made the navigate method run outside the ngzone. Solved it using the Ngzone.run and running the navigate that way.

Comment: could you please share the code for Ngzone.run that you have used. I think, I am facing similar situation in using socket.io with angular